# Accents submit with jquery ajax request and codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, jquery, diacritics

I'm creating a basic form with ajax submit using jquery framework.
This is my code :

```
$('form#contact_form').submit(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: $(this).attr('method'),
        url: $(this).attr('action'),
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        success: function(data) {
        }
    });
});
```

And I use PHP file with simple `var_dump($_POST)` to show the result.

When I test by interrogating simple PHP page, it's working perfectly.

When I test by interrogating function from my contact controller on CodeIgniter, all items of my form which are accents (not special chars, only accents like "éàèù"), the item are empty.

For information, all my files have UTF-8 encoding.

Someone will know how I can fix this problem ?
Thanks,

Comment: are you using $_POST or $this->input->post() in your controller? Can you check with firebug or chrome developer tools what the post data really looks like? And FYI, the submit event has no `return false;` line.

Comment: I try with $_POST and $this->input->post() and I have the same problem.

Comment: For information, in my developer tool there are all my parameters correctly sent to my controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the problem.

Indeed, the CodeIgniter framework process a "cleaning" of input variables into the Input library.

Because I develop from my MAMP server, there is a bug from it. It was necessary to change the charset encoding UTF-8 to utf-8 and it's working now.

Thanks for your interest.

Comment: How did you make this change? I am also experiencing the same problem!

Answer (score 0):

first thing to check : This conditions load the UTF8 library in codeigniter. Test them one by one and check if they all return true.

```
if (
        preg_match('/./u', 'é') === 1                   // PCRE must support UTF-8
        AND function_exists('iconv')                    // iconv must be installed
        AND ini_get('mbstring.func_overload') != 1      // Multibyte string function overloading cannot be enabled
        AND $CFG->item('charset') == 'UTF-8'            // Application charset must be UTF-8
        )
```

Second, there's a function in **libraries/Input.php** named "_clean_input_data". Probably this function is cleaning your data before it gets to the controller.

There are three types of cleaning inside.

```
 // Clean UTF-8 if supported
    if (UTF8_ENABLED === TRUE)
    {
        $str = $this->uni->clean_string($str);
    }

    // Remove control characters
    $str = remove_invisible_characters($str);

    // Should we filter the input data?
    if ($this->_enable_xss === TRUE)
    {
        $str = $this->security->xss_clean($str);
    }
```

Comment: I have test your test and this return true, so all accents passing perfectly. I feel my data are clean between the moment where it sent by ajax and the moment where it receive by the function, so in parent controller maybe.. I continue to search a solution